# putting 2 values in a variable for conditioning purpose SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
if(OBJECT_ID('EgTb')is not null)drop table [EgTB];
GO
create table [EgTB](Name varchar(50),country varchar(50))
insert into EgTB values('aaa','sg');
insert into EgTB values('bbb','uk');
insert into EgTB values('ccc','us');
insert into EgTB values('ddd','au');
GO
select * from EgTB;

declare @cou varchar(50), @firstCou varchar(50), @secondCou varchar(50);
set @firstCou='sg';
set @secondCou='uk';
if(@cou is null)
begin
set @cou=@firstCou+','+@secondCou;
end
select * from EgTB where (@cou is null or country in (@cou));
GO
if(OBJECT_ID('EgTb')is not null)drop table [EgTB];
GO
```

The above code is the one I stimulated.

there is a variable `@cou`.

That variable is the one using in where.

what I want is.. if `@cou` is null, I want to use `@firstCou` and `@secondCou`.

Instead of doing `where country in (@firstCou,@secondCou)`

I want `where country in (@cou)` with those 2 variable values in `@cou`.

cos the real thing is not 2 extra variable.. I will retreieve several records and I won't know the fixed record.

That's why I want to use `IN()`

But my problem is when I add those 2 values into `@cou`, the `@cou` value becomes `'sg,uk'` instead of `'sg','uk'`.

it is expected but how can i make it so that it becomes `'sg','uk'`

Comment: Your question is essentially about parametrising the `IN` clause, which has been covered here many times. Please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause) and possibly pay attention to its *Linked* section as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not replace the parameters for [`IN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) with a string literal. In takes a list of expressions or a sub-query as an argument.

You could use a table variable instead with one column and one row for each country.

```
declare @cou table(country varchar(50))
```

Insert the countries you look for to the table variable and use a query that looks like this.

```
select *
from EgTB
where country in (select country from @cou)
```